# Best approach for dependent ajax calls in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a situation where I need to make 5 ajax calls. The second ajax call will be made after first call returns response, the third call is made when second call completes and likewise fourth and fifth call.

There are 2 approach for this which I know, I could nest ajax calls on success of previous call or make async false before first call and make it true after last call. Could any one suggest which is and WHY it is the better way to accomplish my task or there is some more better way to do this.

```
//First Way
$.ajax({
...
success:function(){
    $.ajax({
    ...
        success:function(){
            $.ajax({
            ...
                success:function(){
                    $.ajax({
                    ...
                        success:function(){
                              do something      
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
});

//second way 
$.ajaxSetup({
    async: false
});
$.ajax({
});
$.ajax({
});
$.ajax({
});
$.ajax({
});
$.ajax({
});
$.ajaxSetup({
    async: true
});
```

Comment: What is the logic that gets executed after each request? Is the logic of each similar, or do you just need to ensure that the calls happen in this sequence? Also note that `async: false` is very bad. Almost `eval` levels of bad ;)

Comment: Let us know the Reason and Situation which lead you to do this please.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan My requirement is that the call happens in sequence one after another

Comment: In that case you will need to chain your calls as in your first example.

Comment: you can use a counter and increment it in the success functions than test at what step you are curently and execute the next ajax

Comment: You need Promises here. To learn more: http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2015/02/promises/ Or jQuery may help you http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Could any one suggest which is and WHY it is the better way to accomplish my task...

Using `async: false` will make the calls *synchronous*, which locks up the UI of the browser while the calls are running. It's better to leave the UI responsive while the calls are running.

So leaving the calls asynchronous is best; there are a few ways to do that:

There's using the `success` handler, as you demonstrated:

```
$.ajax({
    /*...*/,
    success: function() {
        $.ajax({
            /*...*/,
            success: function() {
                $.ajax({
                    /*...*/,
                    success: function() {
                        $.ajax({
                            /*...*/,
                            success: function() {
                                $.ajax({
                                    /*...*/
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

(I'm assuming you've either registered a global ajax error handler, or that you have one in `/*...*/` above.)

There's using a promise chain instead, which is quite similar:

```
$.ajax({/*...*/})
    .done(function() {
        $.ajax({/*...*/})
            .done(function() {
                $.ajax({/*...*/})
                    .done(function() {
                        $.ajax({/*...*/})
                            .done(function() {
                                $.ajax({/*...*/});
                            });
                    });
            });
    });
```

Or you can use a function loop, like so:

```
(function() {
    var calls = [
        function() { $.ajax({/*...*/, success: next)},
        function() { $.ajax({/*...*/, success: next)},
        function() { $.ajax({/*...*/, success: next)},
        function() { $.ajax({/*...*/, success: next)},
        function() { $.ajax({/*...*/, success: next)}
    ];
    var index = 0;
    next();

    function next() {
        if (index < calls.length) {
            // Do the next, increment the call index
            calls[index++]();
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: can we check any outputs of every AJAx call and accordingly call or avoid call of further all AJAX events, like returning false or else?

Comment: @Vikrant: If you're talking about the function loop, no reason you couldn't have a flag that could be set by the `success` or `fail` callback on any given ajax call that stops the "loop" early.

Comment: can we do something like `function() { $.ajax({/*...*/,   
success: function (){   
ret = false;},  
 complete: next})} if(ret == true)  
        function() { $.ajax({/*...*/, complete: next})}, ...`?

Comment: @Vikrant: It would be a lot cleaner with the function loop. Then you just have a flag that's a variable declared next to `index`, and have `next` check the flag.

Comment: Do you wrap it in a closer so that the calls array is cleaned up?  Do I have to worry about cleaning up variable or are there possible memory problems?

Comment: @Terry - That was just for scoping, to avoid creating globals. These days I'd use a module instead. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Any chance of updating your answer to show modules?  i.e. if I just wanted a pipline inside a function that is part of a large js/ts file, are you able to use a module 'inline'?  I thought modules were only able to be declared at root of file?

Comment: @Terry - Correct, an entire compilation unit (loosely, "file") is (or is not) a module. There isn't a concept of an "inline" module.